# Shiny DT::datatable - Change table content when lines are selected

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity

In a datatable some value is supposed to change depending on whether the respective row is selected or not. What makes me a headache is the following: When the data is updated the table is re-written, and the selection is gone.

I have been working on this challenge for a couple of hours but have not come across a solution. Most of the time I find solutions to my problems at stackoverflow, but this time I did not.

In the below example, the last column is supposed to show the row's selection state.  I was trying to keep track of the selected rows and pre-select them whenever the table is re-written. But I could not figure out how to make it work; the code does not work but (hopefully) shows what I need.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
mymtcars = mtcars[1:5, 1:2]

runApp(
     list(ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")),

     server = function(input, output, session) {
       rowSelect <- reactive({
           a <- rep(FALSE,5)
           a[input$mytable_rows_selected] <- TRUE
           return( a ) 
       })

       output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(
           cbind(mymtcars, v=rowSelect()),
           options = list(dom="t",
                          ordering=FALSE),
           selection=list(mode='multiple',
                          selected=(1:5)[rowSelect()],
                          target='row')
       )
   })
)
```

By the way, a less elegant but also possible way would be adding a column of checkboxes instead of the datatable row selection mechanism. I have also tried that, but had similar problems. Everything worked out the way I wanted up to the point where I added reactive columns to my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right! You have to put wrap your table with `datatable`:

```
output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(cbind(mymtcars, v=rowSelect()),
              options = list(dom = "t",ordering = FALSE),
              selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                               selected =(1:5)[rowSelect()],
                               target = "row"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I cannot vote your answer useful as my reputation is too low :-( Maybe you also know how to start the table with all lines selcted?

Comment: @Hans there should be an option in datatable something like `selected = "all"`

Comment: That is tricky as this option is already in use for remembering the previous selection (before table re-write). I can resort to re-interpreting "selected" as "not selected" and vice versa by letting `v = !rowSelect()` but I think it would be more elegant not to "cheat" this way. But anyway, thank you very much, your answer helped me greatly.